Azure ADB2C Local Account and Custom policy
I am trying to swap from a User Flow, to a Custom Policy. I have a SPA Application, and the users are already registered in B2C as a local user. When following the instructions to create a custom flow, it says to create 2 applications, an "Identity Framework Experience" and a "Proxy Identity Framework Experience" - My guess is that in my case, I want to use my existing SPA Application in place of the "Identity Framework Experience"? Every time I try and log in with existing user credentials, I get Invalid Username or Password.
Extensions XML
I have added the SPA App to the IdTokenAudience and resource_id and the Proxy to client_id fields
Is this the right thing to do?

No, these framework applications are separate app. registrations to the SPA.
You could use this utility to set everything up for you.
